# update multiple rows with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have two tables

```
student:
(student_id, student_name)
```

and

```
license:
(license_id, student_id)
```

And I have a list of student ids (for example "3,4,5")

I want to update 3(list size) rows in table license and change their student_id field from null to 3,4,5 respectively.

How do I do that?
Running a loop of updates is not a suitable solution for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBM you are using? you tag both mysql and oracle.You need to use PL/SQL

Comment: are there existing rows in license table with null value in student_id.  Do you want to insert records in this table or update.

Comment: I am using mysql, though we are considering to move for Oracle.

Comment: there already exists a lot of rows with sutdent_id=null in the 'license' table

Comment: What is the Primary Key of table `licence`? Is it `licence_id`?

Answer (score 1):

I have an MS SQL version of an id parser. You can use this to generate a table with a single column that contains your ids it takes a parameter of type varchar(max). you can use it on a select statement like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE COLUMNAME IN (SELECT value FROM parseIDs ('1,2,3'))
```

Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION parseIDs  
(
    @IDList VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @IDs TABLE (value VARCHAR(80))
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IDList is null
        RETURN

    DECLARE @Len INT, 
            @Pos INT, 
            @Cur INT

    SELECT @Pos = 0, 
           @Len = 0, 
           @Cur = 1, 
           @IDList =  CASE 
                        WHEN SUBSTRING(@IDList, LEN(@IDList), 1) = ',' THEN @IDList 
                        ELSE @IDList + ',' 
                      END

    SELECT @Pos = CHARINDEX( ',', @IDList, @Cur)
    WHILE (@Pos <> 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT @IDs VALUES (LTRIM(SUBSTRING( @IDList, @Cur, (@Pos - @Cur))))
        SELECT @Cur = @Pos + 1
        SELECT @Pos = CHARINDEX( ',', @IDList, @Cur)
    END
    return
END
```

Comment: Allan, thank you. This would become handy. But it's not the main problem. The problem is update query itself. How would it look like?

Comment: @user1014523 anytime buddy ;).. We always find this function very useful when using SQL server :)

Comment: This can be helpful for SQL-Server but doesn't answer the question. MySQL has `FIND_IN_SET()` function which does a similar thing.